# What are the "panels" on the wingtips of the Panavia Tornado?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, fighter, feature-identification, panavia-tornado

I am wondering about the purpose of the panel marked with the number 156 in this picture:
[image: Tsfdoshis]

The same black panel can be seen on the wingtips here:
[image: wingtip panel]

And also here:
[image: wingtip panel]

What purpose does this panel serve? It could be just a construction technique, but in that case why would they cut a hole in the larger panel just to cover it up with the smaller black one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From another cutaway drawing:

> > **57: Wing tip antenna**

[image]

<sup>Found [here](https://weaponsandwarfare.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/fmujujfmu.jpg), but the original source is unknown.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! In all the cutaway pictures I could find this part was missing or the text was unreadable, somehows I missed this one.

Any idea what the antenna would be used for?

Comment: Maybe somebody around here will know exactly, but the fact that they are only visible on some aircraft makes me think they are part of an optional or retrofitted communication link.

Comment: I worked on GR1s and they weren't fitted to those.